# Graphics2d draw text with partial bold text

Tags: java, graphics2d

I was wondering if I can make a partial bold text for example:

Please make your assignment before **21 of july**

I have not tried anything yet, because i just have no clue how to do this.

Here is my code currently for rendering text:

```
public void renderText(int page, String text, String font, int fontSize, Color color, int width, int height) {
       final Graphics2D g;
       if (page == 1) {
           g = (Graphics2D) outsideFlyer.getGraphics();
           g.drawImage(outsideFlyer, 0, 0, null);
       } else {
           g = (Graphics2D) insideFlyer.getGraphics();
           g.drawImage(insideFlyer, 0, 0, null);
       }
       if (font == null) {
           g.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
       } else if ("bold".equals(font)) {
           g.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, fontSize));
       } else {
           g.setFont(new Font(font, Font.PLAIN, fontSize));
       }
       g.setColor(color);
       for (String txt : text.split("\n")) {
           g.drawString(txt, width, height += g.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
       }
       g.dispose();
   }
```

Is it possible to split the text in some way?
I would love to have something like what happens on a lot of websites like everything inbetween * gets bold or in some way.

Comment: You have to split your text, render the first part with a plain font, then render the second part with a bold font.  The trick is calculating the x position of the second part accurately, so it looks like one text rendering,  You can use the FontMetrics class to get the width of the first part of the text.

Comment: What are the types of `outsideFlyer` and `insideFlyer`?  If they’re components, you are obtaining your Graphics2D object the wrong way.  You don’t actively draw on a component;  you wait for the system to create its own Graphics object and pass it to your overridden paintComponent method.  That said, you’re probably better off creating one JLabel per line than doing custom drawing;  the bold font can be achieved using HTML in a JLabel’s text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. After some research in other posts as well, I figured out a solution(at least it solved my problem).

First, as far as I know, you can't do it in the same string, so you have to split it and draw them separately.

Second, you need to get the width/height(depending on your case) that the first string occupies in your scenario. You can use your Graphics2D instance to get it, given your font, font size, etc. Then you can use this information to calculate the according position of the second string.

Code example:

```
String plainText = "Please make your assignment before ";
String boldText = "21 of july";
Graphics2D graphics2D = g; //will assume that you already configured it your way
g.setFont(yourPlainFont);
g.drawString(plainText, positionX, positionY);
int plainTextSize = g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(plainText);
g.setFont(yourBoldFont);
g.drawString(boldText, positionX + plainTextSize, positionY);
```

Please note that this example is only considering a text in the same line, as asked by OP. You should be able to do the same in different lines(heights) as well, although I didn't test that way. Hope it helps.